# Why suddenly the port cannot be connected?

Tags: macos, networking, java, ipad

I am running a HTTP Server on my Mac, which is a NanoHTTP Server, not Apache etc. I use eclipse to run it, it runs, and work perfectly, and I got an iPad to access it, it works. The firewall on Mac is allow the Java to use the port. Then, after a while I working with my Server and iPad, it can't access again. I can access the Server from my Mac, using the `192.168.1.6:6777`, which is the DHCP signed ip and port, it works previously, but now, is not working on iPad, but on the Mac, it is not problem at all. The iPad just say it is `The request timed out.` What's can be happened? I use `netstat` to check the port, it is working with a Java programme, which make prefect sense. But when I reboot my Mac, is working again. Any clues on that? Thanks.

Here is my Firewall setting, does it matter?:
[image]